Conditionally inserting commas in variable-length lines
I have a file that used to contain two CSV columns but has had its commas removed so that each line is one full "record". I need to separate these into two records again by adding a comma, but the lines are between 20 to 21 characters and need to be processed accordingly - if the line is 20 characters the comma needs to be added at the 16th position, and if the line is 21 characters the comma needs to be added at the 17th position. If I've done my maths right this would result in a second column that has 5 characters on all lines.
What's the best way to accomplish this using Bash and GNU tools?

consider reviewing how to create a minimal reproducible example then come back and update the question; in particular, show sample test data (line that does not need changed, lines that do need to be changed (1x20char, 1x21char), the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected result

What have you tried so far?

With sed:
sed -E 's/.{5}$/,&/' file

